# Bash script, can't wait for eval command to finish when called in a function

Tags: bash

What I am trying to do is create a generic, asynchronous command runner that will allow me to run a command in the background and get its output and code without blocking the shell I am working in (think serial). For most commands, I could do something like:

```
FUNCwaitForCommand() {
    wait "$1"
    echo $? > "code.txt"
}
ls > "output.txt" &
pid=$!
FUNCwaitForCommand $pid &
```

however, this does not work for composed commands, e.g.

```
(cat < somefifo)
```

I can make it run the commands with something like:

```
FUNCwaitForCommand() {                                                                                    
    wait $1                                                                                               
    echo $? > code                                                                                        
}
eval "ls > output.txt &"
pid=$!
FUNCwaitForCommand $pid &
```

but the wait does not wait. I can make it wait to finish until the process finishes by doing:

```
while kill -0 "$1"; do wait "$1"; done
```

instead of just wait, but the code it gives me is 127 instead of the code of the command that gets run. If I put a wait directly after the pid collection

```
eval "ls > output.txt &"
pid=$!
wait $pid
```

it waits for the process just fine, but obviously it doesn't background and release the shell back to me.

I'm not great at bash, but it looks like inside of the function is not in the same sub shell as the eval, so it doesn't recognize the background process, though I don't know why it only acts that way when using eval, and not when using the normal execution method.

Comment: Has nothing to do with it being a function, and everything to do with you backgrounding the function.

Comment: That is to say, `FUNCwaitForCommand $pid &` won't work any more than `wait $pid &` will.

Comment: Not only does this not have anything to do with functions, btw, it *also* doesn't have anything to do with `eval`. Please try harder to make your [mcve] truly minimal in the future -- simplifying out any aspect of the reproducer that isn't actually necessary to recreate the problem.

Comment: Based on my testing, I did believe this to be a minimal example. It seems that the problem there rests with the fact that, as you can see, I believed it to work when not using eval. I remember testing that earlier this morning while I was debugging and formulating this question, and I remember it working. This thought was bolstered by the fact that this code has been running in production for months. However, as usual, the human brain is not nearly as reliable as we like to think it is, so I came with incomplete information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explanation

Just as you can't use:

```
sleep 5 & pid=$!
wait $pid &
```

you can't put that wait inside a backgrounded function either. That is to say, you *can* run:

```
sleep 5 & pid=$!
waitForCommand() { wait "$@"; }
waitForCommand "$pid"
```

but you *can't* run:

```
sleep 5 & pid=$!
waitForCommand() { wait "$@"; }
waitForCommand "$pid" &
```

This is because processes can only `wait()` for their children. When you fork off a new child off the shell with `&`, you're no longer the parent -- instead, you're a sibling. As such, this isn't shell-specific behavior but general-purpose UNIX semantics -- you'd get an equivalent error in *any* language.

---

#### Workaround

Ensure that exit-status recording is done by the direct parent of the process whose exit status is being recorded, *even if that parent itself is in the background relative to the original shell*.

```
tempdir_top=$(mktemp -t -d bgdir.XXXXXX)
declare -g -A tempdirs=( )

runBackgroundCommand() {
  (( "$#" == 1 )) || { echo "Usage: runBackgroundCommand 'command'" >&2; return 1; }
  local cmd tempdir
  cmd=$1
  tempdir=$(mktemp -d "$tempdir_top/proc.XXXXXX")
  {
    printf '%s\0' "$cmd" >"$tempdir/cmd"
    eval "$cmd" >"$tempdir/stdout" 2>"$tempdir/stderr" & pid=$!
    printf '%s\n' "$pid" >"$tempdir/pid"
    wait "$1"; retval=$?
    printf '%s\n' "$retval" >"$tempdir/retval"
  } &
  tempdirs[$tempdir]=$!
}

# example usage
runBackgroundCommand "sleep 5"
runBackgroundCommand "sleep 10"
```

That way, in the parent process, you have a map of temporary directories to the top-level PID for each (easily used to check for completion), and can look inside that directory for more information on any of the processes involved.

Comment: `wait $pid` instead of `wait "$1"`?

Comment: Thanks, writing the pid to a file was the piece I was missing to make this work originally. Not sure why that didn't occur to me, but using that idea I was able to get this working.

Comment: @codeforester, ...so, I *did* have that mistake nested inside a function inside one of the original revisions of this (collapsed into the initial 5-minute edit window), but the `$pid` entries still there in this answer as of the time when your comment was added are all ones I intend to be there, because they're all either top-level or scoped inside a subshell.